# ¿Existe alguna forma de determinar onMouseOut a la derecha o onMouseOut a la izquierda?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un botón al que le tengo asociado el evento `onMouseOut`

```
      <button id="boton"  onMouseOut={hago algo}

      </button>
```

¿Existe alguna manera de detectar cuando me salgo del botón por la derecha con `onMouseOut` o cuando me salgo del botón por la izquierda con `onMouseOut`? En otras palabras: al posicionarme con el mouse sobre mi botón y luego mover al mouse a mi derecha, ¿existe alguna forma de que `onMouseOut` me diga que me salí por mi derecha? o al posicionarme con el mouse sobre mi botón y luego mover al mouse a mi izquierda, ¿existe alguna forma de que `onMouseOut` me diga que me salí por mi izquierda?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siendo más específico en mi pregunta, lo que deseo hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Al posicionarme sobre el botón menos(-) aparezca visible el cuadro negro (el que contiene el zoom y el texto Mostrar el control deslizante 1).
2. Al posicionarme sobre el botón menos(-) y desplazar el mouse hacia la izquierda sobre el cuadro negro se siga manteniendo el cuadro negro visible.
3. AL sacar el mouse de este cuadro negro desaparezca este cuadro negro.
4. Al posicionarme sobre el botón menos(-)  y aparecer el cuadro negro luego al sacar el mouse fuera del botón menos(-) desaparezca el cuadro negro (aquí es importante acotar que necesito que al estar posicionado sobre el botón menos(-) y moverlo hacia mi mano derecha el cuadro negro debe desaparecer, pero si estoy sobre el botón menos(-) y me muevo hacia mi mano izquierda y estoy sobre el cuadro negro este no quiero que desaparezca).

No me ha sido fácil lograr el punto 4, pero los cuatro puntos indican lo que deseo lograr.

Acá parte del código:

```
const mostrarMensajeControlDeslizante = (e) =>{  

      document.getElementById("mensaje_resta").style="visibility: `visible;"
      document.getElementById("triangulo_resta").style="visibility: visible;" 
      document.getElementById("p").style="visibility: visible;"
      document.getElementById("a").style="visibility: visible;" 

}

const ocultarMensajeControlDeslizante1 = (e) =>{

      document.getElementById("mensaje_resta").style="visibility: `visible;"
      document.getElementById("triangulo_resta").style="visibility: visible;" 
      document.getElementById("p").style="visibility: visible;"
      document.getElementById("a").style="visibility: visible;" 

}

return(
         {BOTON RESTA}
          <button id="btn-resta"  
              onMouseOver={mostrarMensajeControlDeslizante} 
              onMouseOut={ocultarMensajeControlDeslizante}
              >
                <i id="fa-minus" className="fas fa-minus"></i>
          </button>


          {ESTE ES EL RECUADRO NEGRO}
         
            <div  id="mensaje_resta"  >      
                <p id="p">Zoom</p>
                <a id="a" >Mostrar el control deslizante 1</a>
            </div>
            <div id="triangulo_resta"  
              >               
            </div> 
)
```

Comment: Necesitarás capturar la posición del cursor a través de la propiedad `clientX` y en cada movimiento (evento `mousemove`) almacenar la posición del cursor, de tal manera que cuando se produzca el evento de salida solo necesites comparar la nueva posición con la anterior. Si es mayor, se fue por la derecha, y si es menor, por la izquierda.

Comment: Hola Alexis, tienes algun modelo de codigo para visualizar lo que me indicas ?

Comment: Será necesario que muestres tu intento en código o los policías de StackOverflow van a aparecerse por aquí.

Comment: Si la información que te ha dado Alexis88 ni te suena, una buena idea es buscarla en Google, y podrás llegar a esto: https://es.javascript.info/mouse-events-basics

Comment: Puede poner algo (un <span> o <div> tal vez) a la izquierda y la derecha y cuando entre a esos, sabe cual direccion fue.

Comment: Creo que lo que te dijo Alexis pasa por saber en que coordenada esta tu cursor, por ejemplo si pasas desde derecha a izquierda tu coordenada en `x` será menor que si la pasas de izquierda a derecha podrías ver los valores haciendo un debug en tu js y después codear en base a lo que ves. Este link te enseñara como ver las coordenada de tu puntero (https://programmerclick.com/article/850495838/).

Comment: he intentado todo lo que me aconsejan pero ha sido infructuoso, no he logrado el objetivo, hacer esto no es nada facil.......

Comment: @Alexis88, tu comentario es muy bueno, ¿por qué no creas la respuesta?

Comment: @Triby Qué bueno encontrarte por aquí, amigo. Ahí voy.

Comment: @Alexis88 ¡Lo mismo digo!

Comment: Asi es ayudenme con algun codigo Triby y Alexis88 porfa

Answer (score 2):

He pensado en una mejor solución que la de mi comentario. Solo hace falta lo siguiente:

En el momento en el que se produzca el evento de salida en el elemento, captura la posición del cursor y compáralo con los bordes izquierdo y derecho los cuales puedes obtener por medio del método `getBoundingClientRect()`. El resto es lo mismo: si la posición es menor al borde izquierdo, el cursor se fue por la izquierda; y si es mayor al borde derecho, se fue por la derecha.

Como no tengo un ordenador a la mano, adjunto una imagen con el código de ejemplo (intenté escribirlo, pero no me deja publicarlo). Trata de adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Si algo va mal, me avisas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Corrección: El cálculo de los bordes se puede hacer por fuera de esa función dado que no va a variar.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alexis88 por tu intencion de ayudarme, buena logica, al final logre hacerlo con solo onMouseOver y onMouseOut...Gracias tambien a los otros compañeros por sus contribuciones.

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero en SO se pide que el código se publique como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: @Triby No se me ha permitido publicar el código (lo indiqué en la descripción). Estoy únicamente con un teléfono móvil por estos días, y cuando he escrito el código en intentado publicarlo, se me indicó que debía darle formato, pero en la vista para móviles no se encuentran las herramientas de formato; y forzando la vista de escritorio en el móvil, por un tema de espacio físico no se podía pulsar los botones de las herramientas de formato. Solo me quedó escribir el código en un IDE para móviles, tomar una captura y subirla.

Comment: @Alexis88, puedes agregarlo junto con la imagen y, en caso de que no puedas formatearlo, seguramente alguien lo hará por ti.

Comment: @Triby Desde un inicio lo intenté así pensando añadir un texto extra pidiendo que se formatee el código, pero directamente se mostró un mensaje en letras rojas advirtiendo que no podía añadir el código debido a la falta de formato. De hecho, al intentar publicarlo, se me indicaba que debía resolver ese problema. Por eso es que no me quedó otra opción que adjuntar esa imagen.